# Как запретить zoom в WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview

Заметил, что на некоторых устройствах, компонент WebView позволяет увеличить и уменьшить масштаб. Как поставить запрет на это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не путаю, то на API 11+ можно так:

```
wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wv.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

Если нужно везде, то можно создать свой класс, унаследовав его от `WebView` и переопределить `OnTouchEvent`.

Что-то вроде кода из [этого](http://%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE) вопроса:

```
if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ||
            ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN ||
            ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN ||
            ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN ||
            ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_3_DOWN) {
        if (multiTouchZoom && !buttonsZoom) {
            if (getPointerCount(ev) > 1) {
                getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            } else {
                getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
                getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            }
        }
    }

    if (!multiTouchZoom && buttonsZoom) {
        if (getPointerCount(ev) > 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Благодарю! Хотелось бы конечно чтобы под API 10 тоже работало, но видимо это невозможно.